# Destruction order of class data members?

Tags: c++, destructor, operator-precedence

Imagine a class like this:

```
class foo {
public:
    foo() : _bar{new bar}, _baz{new baz} {}
private:
    unique_ptr<bar> _bar;
    unique_ptr<baz> _baz;
};
```

So whenever an instance of `foo` gets destructed, then in what order will the data members of it be destroyed, if that's defined behavior at all?

Let's say that `_baz` does depend on the existance of `_bar`, maybe it uses some resource that `_bar` owns (let's assume it knows about the `_bar` object, even though the constructor doesn't reflect this).
So in this case, if `_bar` gets destructed first (when its time to destruct `foo`), then `_baz` could potentially try to access some resource which has been freed by `_bar`'s destructor.

An obvious solution is to implement a destructor in `foo`, which manually frees `_baz` and `_bar` in the right order, but what if there's no destructor implemented? Is there a default behavior that defines the destruction order of data members?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The order of destruction of data members is the reverse of their order of declaration, the same way as variables declared within a scope:

```
{
  // a, b constructed in that order
  bar a;
  baz b;

} // b, a destroyed in that order
```

Comment: Just to include this is defined in 12.4 (8): ...Bases and
members are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their constructor...